# Windows Container - How to commit a container

Tags: windows, docker

I am running a windows container on Windows Server 2016 and have made some changes on the base image. Now want to commit it but when I run

```
docker commit <containerId> <imageName>
```

I get the following error

Error response from daemon: Windows does not support commit of a running container.

Wondering if anyone has a solution to this. How would you otherwise build your containers if committing is not possible?

Comment: When I said "Wondering if anyone has a solution to this. How would you otherwise build your containers if committing is not possible?", I actually meant building an image from a base image, so something like starting from microsoft/nanoserver and add software to it

Comment: PS: The state of the container can be saved with the save command e.g. 

docker save -o C:\filenamet.tar microsoft/nanoserver

Comment: So, the answer is it is not supported yet.
The version of docker I used is 

Docker version 1.13.0-dev, build 2a3ba03

Comment: `docker commit` isn't supported on Windows, but it's not the recommended way to build images anyway - it's not repeatable, so you can't easily update your image. [Writing a Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) which starts `FROM microsoft/nanoserver` and adds your setup is much preferred. See Microsoft's [Windows container samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/tree/master/windows-container-samples)

Comment: thanks for the pointer Elton Stoneman. I will try to use one. Have always used docker images for non-production throw away images. Came as a surprise that it's not supported yet. There are definitely alternatives

Comment: You have selected the wrong answer: your question was about committing a running container. The answer points to an article which stops the container first, then commit.

Comment: Got it. sorry. It's been a while since I posted this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from [`daemon/commit.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/b248de7e332b6e67b08a8981f68060e6ae629ccf/daemon/commit.go#L128-L131)

```
// It is not possible to commit a running container on Windows
if runtime.GOOS == "windows" && container.IsRunning() {
    return "", fmt.Errorf("Windows does not support commit of a running container")
}
```

As [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) mentions:

> By default, the container being committed and its processes will be paused while the image is committed.

But implementing pause resume for Windows is only now being done with [PR 26795](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/26795), and [commit dd38389](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/dd383898cdcbcef7bd48bc0115cc9a739cf610f3) for [`docker pause`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pause/).
Commit could follow soon after that.

> How would you otherwise build your containers if committing is not possible?

Committing is about saving a container as an image (or "building" an image), not about building a container.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Saving the container as an image is exactly what I want to do. I want to take a base image microsoft/nanoserver for instance and add some configuration, installation, etc on it and save it as an image

Comment: Thanks for your answer VonC. So the answer is at this stage it is not supported.

Comment: Yes, it is not yet supported

Comment: @HamidShahid Current 2017 code: https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/b248de7e332b6e67b08a8981f68060e6ae629ccf/daemon/commit.go#L128-L131: both Windows *and* Solaris do not support committing a running container.

Comment: I realize this is a bit old for this maturing technology, but `docker save` indicates it wants the IMAGE as an argument, not a container.. your answer indicates 'saving a container as an image', can you clarify how?

Comment: @BrettCaswell my answer is about `docker commit`, not `docker save`.

Answer (score 5):

This now works, see this [blog post](http://www.ntweekly.com/?p=14587) for full info.  All you have to do is stop the container and then use 'docker ps -a' to show all containers (even ones no longer running).  Find the container you want to create the image from, then use the usual 'docker commit {containerid} {newimagename}'.  Since it is no longer running, the commit will succeed and you will see the new image in the output of 'docker images ls'.

Comment: In addition to stopping the container first (because just pausing the Windows container still did not allow me to commit it), I had to exit out of any interactive terminal `exec -it` session that was running otherwise I would get an error when trying to commit the stopped container. After exiting any interactive sessions and stopping the container, I was then able to commit it.

Comment: wouldn't stopping the container lose the data..?

Comment: I lost all data after "stopping". I am running MSSQL and created some and created some databases

Comment: This is what I have learnt. Use mounted volumes to make the container write stateful information out to the container. I am on Windows. I mounted a volume while doing a DOCKER RUN and had MSSQL write all data files to the mounted volume.  By doing this I am able to restore the "state" of the MSSQL.

Comment: You want to commit to preserve the changes done to a container, yet you recommend stopping the container first, which will lose all changes...

Answer (score -3):

The simplest and most dependable way to build any kind of container image is to use a `Dockerfile` and `docker build`. Both of these work great with Docker Windows containers. Details here:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/docker/manage_windows_dockerfile
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/docker/optimize_windows_dockerfile